# Enable "cancel" order action button for specific order statuses in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

In Woocommerce My account Orders, I am using the following code to Check if customer orders are in "processing" or "shipped" status and if it is the case, display a button to cancel the order:

```
    if ($order_status == 'processing' || $order_status == 'shipped' ){
    echo '<a href="click=1" class="woocommerce-button button return">Return Order</a>';
        $order->update_status('cancelled');
}
```

With my code, the order get automatically updated to cancel status when the status was "processing" or "shipped" and I can't get the button to work. I want to make that happen on button click to trigger the update_status. 
  I want to make it appear in view order page like this
[image] Right now the cancel order isn't functional
How can I do? without using Javascript?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will enable the Woocommerce **"cancel"** cation button in My account orders list, also for `processing` or `shipped` order statuses *(default Woocommerce statuses are here `pending` and `failed`)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 10, 1 );
function custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses ){

    // Set HERE the order statuses where you want the cancel button to appear
    return array_merge( $statuses, array('processing', 'shipped'));
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i copy pasted your code into my functions.php but it didn't work what did i do wrong? without changing anything

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is it possible to restrict the time the button appears for - for example for only 48 hours?